# Connection refused to LDAP (Java)

Tags: java, network-programming, ldap

I am connecting to LDAP, which is working fine. However, I need to change the value of one attribute. I am able to read the current value, but I can't modify the value. This is my code:

I have tried many things from the internet, but all cause in one error:

```
  [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect] (It's always in the "executing" line of code).
   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapReferralContext.<init>(LdapReferralContext.java:74)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapReferralException.getReferralContext(LdapReferralException.java:132)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:410)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:357)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.p_bind(ComponentContext.java:596)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.bind(PartialCompositeContext.java:183)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.bind(PartialCompositeContext.java:173)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:400)
at Client.connect(Client.java:80)
at Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:570)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:371)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:316)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:186)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:116)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1580)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2678)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:296)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:134)
at com.sun.jndi.url.ldap.ldapURLContextFactory.getObjectInstance(ldapURLContextFactory.java:35)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLObject(NamingManager.java:584)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.processURL(NamingManager.java:364)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.processURLAddrs(NamingManager.java:344)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:316)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapReferralContext.<init>(LdapReferralContext.java:93)
```

This is what I tried - what am I doing wrong? Please give me some suggestions.

```
 Attribute mod0 = new BasicAttribute("attribute", "AAA");
 mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, mod0); 
 authContext.modifyAttributes("correctDn", mods);
```

Later, I tried this one:

```
 Attribute acl = new BasicAttribute( "attribute", "asdf");
 authContext.modify( entryDN, new LDAPModification(LDAPModification.ADD, acl));
```

Comment: Does your user have the privileges to do that?

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: I am not sure about the privileges. How can I find that out?
I'll post the complete error message in the question.

Comment: The client is being notified of a connection refused.

Comment: @user714965 What privileges? You don't need special privileges to connect to a TCP port.

Comment: @EJP: It's not about connecting, as the connection works fine until I try to modify something.

Comment: Certainly it's about connecting. You're getting 'connection refused'. That's *all* that it's about.

Comment: Why can I read everything from this LDAP when it's about the connection?

Comment: @Nicky Read my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED** This is a connection refusal while processing a referral. You are talking to an LDAP slave that has sent you a referral to the master, and you can't connect to the master, either because the slave configuration has given you the wrong referral information or because there is a firewall in the way of the master LDAP server.

Comment: Please read my question before commenting. As I told you, I am able to read from this LDAP - so it has to exist, doesn't it :)

Comment: It may come from referrals built with "mydomain.ltd" and some of DCs listed by the DNS alias "mydomain.ltd" are not available from your code location.